# pagination in rmarkdown of subset in to multiple pages

Tags: r

I am new in R. The result of a `subset` is more than 3750 records of the dataset.
Currently, it shows all the records, and it makes the page very long.
So, **is there anyway that i show the results in [pages](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp) of 10 records.**

Here is my subset

```
subset(adult,as.numeric(age)<as.numeric(range[1]) ,select=(age))
```

Comment: The DT library makes it possible to generate interactive tables that you can page through. You can easily limit number of rows on each page. https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: Just subset to the rows you want, e.g. `...[21:30, ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatable html widget should accomplish this for you: http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_datatables.html